# Angular Navigation Strategy

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-router

i am building an angular app but my html structure is a little bit different i have Multi Purpose Template so instead of having single pages so the user can navigate between those pages they all stack on top of each other. I have 3 components:

- HomeComponent
- AboutComponent
- NavbarComponent - with 2 anchor tags to scrolldown to the target section

Template NavbarComponent:

```
<div>
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

Template HomeComponent:

```
<div>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    lorem...
</div>
```

Template AboutComponent:

```
<div>
    <h1>About</h1>
    lorem...
</div>
```

Template AppComponent:

```
<navbar></navbar>
<home id="home"></home>
<about id="about"></about>
```

[here's the demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytr4c4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

So my problem is instead of having myapp.com/#home or myapp.com/#about when the user click on the link how can i have the url in that format: **myapp.com/home** based on the structure of my template in app.component.html and i will scroll the window down to the target section based on the url but i need to know how to change the behavior because if i do it that way:

```
<a href="/home">Home</a>
```

the browser will make a GET request

Answer (score 0):

> So my problem is instead of having myapp.com/#home or myapp.com/#about when the user click on the link how can i have the url in that format: myapp.com/home

I just made a super small sample project for you. It provides exactly functionality that you want.

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/xj8pvl18lq

### 1. In the `app.module.ts` , we will have something like this:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, AboutComponent, HomeComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### 2. In the `app.component.ts`, we have:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      <a routerLink="/">Home</a>
      <a routerLink="/about">About</a>
      <hr/>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

### 3. And these are two super simple components: Home Component and About Component

`home.component.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `
        <div>
            <h2>Home</h2>
        </div>
    `
})
export class HomeComponent {}
```

`about.component.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  template: `
        <div>
            <h2>About</h2>
        </div>
    `
})
export class AboutComponent {}
```

Give it a try, hopefully it works as you expected.

Comment: You've provided a working example, but haven't explained how this solves his question.

Comment: Thanks, for the example but in my case i have a different template i'm using a multi purpose template which means the user won't be navigating between pages